# Can't get sfdx force:package:install to block in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: salesforcedx, continuous-integration, jenkins, jenkinsfile

Using the Jenkinsfile mechanism - see the Salesforce [Jenkinsfile Walkthrough](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ci_jenkins_sample_walkthrough.htm) - allows one Continuous Integration (CI) definition to automatically build multiple branches and multiple pull requests via multiple scratch orgs. So it fits well with an SFDX/Git setup.

But I can't find a way to get the [sh](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script) executions in this step:

```
stage('Add other packages') {
    // Need to block until the installs are done
    sh "sfdx force:package:install --wait 15 --package ${A_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID} --installationkey ${A_PACKAGE_PASSWORD}"
    sh "sfdx force:package:install --wait 15 --package ${B_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID} --installationkey ${B_PACKAGE_PASSWORD}"
}
```

to block so that the packages are installed before following tests that depend on those packages run.

If you have this blocking working, please share.

(Note that the Jenkins file adds another layer that seems to stop this  [salesforce DX installing managed package and status response in an automated environment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200317/salesforce-dx-installing-managed-package-and-status-response-in-an-automated-env) from being sufficient.)

**PS**

Thought this might work:

```
stage('Add other packages') {
    echo "Installing A"
    timeout(900) {
        waitUntil {
            sh "sfdx force:package:install --package ${A_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID} --installationkey ${A_PACKAGE_PASSWORD} --wait 15"
        }
    }
    echo "A installed"
```

based on [Make Jenkins pipeline wait until server is up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37920830/make-jenkins-pipeline-wait-until-server-is-up) but I get silent failure immediately after the first `echo`.

**PPS**

Both these managed packages include "Remote Site Settings" that normally require a manual confirmation.

Comment: Is the observed behavior that the subshell returns immediately and SFDX spins in the background? (Just asking, I'm not particularly familiar with Jenkins).

Comment: @DavidReed Yes, I assume the install continues. But a colleague has just pointed out that adding `--noprompt` looks like it fixes the problem; without that the `sfdx force:package:install` is probably waiting for user input as we have remote site definitions in our package and that is blocking the waiting somehow. I've asked him to post an answer here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some installations prompt you for permissions/confirmations.

Check the build failure log and see if there's some pending prompting during your `Add other packages` stage.

If that's the case, add the `--noprompt` option to the `sfdx force:package:install` command.

**Explanation**

If `sfdx` prompts the user for confirmations, my guess is that since there's no console attached it just aborts the process.

Comment: Thanks Francesco. Looks like this is the solution. (I think I was getting a return status of zero when I checked though.)